# How to check if password is less than 8 chars in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to check if the user's pasword or username is less than 8 characters, I have done this before but just by using `onsubmit="return Validation()"` in my form, and it was working that way. But now I am sending form thru ajax and I do not know how to convert or insert the following code in my ajax code.

Below is my code which I want to include inside my ajax code so when I submit the form, it will check if the user has less than 8 characters username and password.

```
function Validation(){
var username = document.getElementById ("username");            
var password = document.getElementById ("password");

var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var password2 = $("#password2").val();

var user_textBox = document.getElementById("username");
var user_textLength = user_textBox.value.length;

var pw_textBox = document.getElementById("password");
var pw_textLength = pw_textBox.value.length;

var x = email;
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if(user_textLength <= 7){
    alert('Username must contain atleast 8 characters.');
    document.getElementById ("username").focus();
    return false;
    }
    else if(pw_textLength <= 7){
        alert('Password must contain atleast 8 characters.');
        document.getElementById ("password").focus();
        return false;
        }
    else if(password2==""){
        alert('Please re-type your password');
        document.getElementById ("password2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(password != password2){
        alert('Password and Re-typed Password do not match');
        document.getElementById ("password2").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        document.getElementById ("email").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Below here is my ajax code.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    function submitForm()
    {       
        var data = $("#signUpForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            // code here...
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#signUpForm").on("submit",submitForm);
    document.forms["signUpForm"].reset();
});
```

EDIT:
What my code looks like now

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#signUpForm').submit(function(e)){
        function Validation() {
            var username = document.getElementById ("username");            
            var password = document.getElementById ("password");

            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var password2 = $("#password2").val();

            var user_textBox = document.getElementById("username");
            var user_textLength = username.trim().length;

            var pw_textBox = document.getElementById("password");
            var pw_textLength = password.trim().length;

            var x = email;
            var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if(user_textLength <= 7){
                    alert('Username must contain atleast 8 characters.');
                    document.getElementById ("username").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(pw_textLength <= 7){
                    alert('Password must contain atleast 8 characters.');
                    document.getElementById ("password").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(password2==""){
                    alert('Please re-type your password');
                    document.getElementById ("password2").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(password != password2){
                    alert('Password and Re-typed Password do not match');
                    document.getElementById ("password2").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(email==""){
                    alert('Please input your email');
                    document.getElementById ("email").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                    document.getElementById ("email").focus();
                    return false;
                }

                else{
                    return true;
                }
        }
        if(!Validation()){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            //var data = $("#signUpForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({

                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'signup.php',
                data : $(this).serialize()
                beforeSend: function()
                {   
                    $("#error").fadeOut();
                    },
                success :  function(data)
                           {                        
                                if(data==2){

                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                                            alert('Email is already taken.');
                                            document.getElementById ("email").focus();

                                    });

                                }
                                else if(data==1){
                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                                            alert('Username is already taken.');
                                            document.getElementById ("username").focus();
                                    });
                                }
                                else if(data==3)
                                {

                                    alert('Registration successfully submitted.');
                                    window.location='index.php';

                                }
                                else{

                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                                    });

                                }
                           }
                });
                return false;
            }
    });
     $("#signUpForm").on("submit",submitForm);
     document.forms["signUpForm"].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same:

```
    if(user_textLength <= 7){
       return false; // function breaks here, following sentences will not execute
    }
    var data = $("#signUpForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
         //....
```

Comment: i did this awhile ago, it does check the textLength, but if all is fixed and i submit the form, it just reloads the page..

Comment: You need to prevent the default behaviour, normally: `form.on('submit', function( event ) { event.preventDefault(); });`, the `event.preventDefault()` in your length check.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of your values by just looking at the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property possibly after a [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) call if you want to ignore leading or trailing white-space :

```
function Validation(){
    // Get your properties
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();

    // Validation example
    if(username.trim().length < 8){
         // Something is wrong, tell the user
         return false;
    }

    // Continue as necessary
}
```

Since you are already using jQuery, you could just wire up an event handler to capture your form submission event as follows :

```
$(function(){
     // When your form is submitted
     $('#signUpForm').submit(function(e){
           // Validate here
           if(!Validation()){
                // Validation failed
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
           } else {
               // Otherwise handle your AJAX request
               $.ajax({
                   // Various things here
                   data: $(this).serialize()
               });
           }
     });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since you have recently added your code, I'll refactor it a bit by removing your `Validation()` function from being scoped within your form submission, removed any default submission behavior (as it is handled via AJAX it seems) and removed any native Javascript calls in favor of jQuery (since you are already using it) :

```
<script>
     function Validation() {
            // Define your variables
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var password2 = $("#password2").val();
            // Get your lengths
            var user_textLength = username.trim().length;
            var pw_textLength = password.trim().length;

            var x = email;
            var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if(user_textLength <= 7){
                    alert('Username must contain atleast 8 characters.');
                    $("#username").focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else if(pw_textLength <= 7){
                    alert('Password must contain atleast 8 characters.');
                    $("#password").focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else if(password2.length == 0){
                    alert('Please re-type your password');
                    $("#password2").focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else if(password != password2){
                    alert('Password and Re-typed Password do not match');
                    $("#password2").focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else if(email.length == 0){
                    alert('Please input your email');
                    $("#email").focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                    $("#email").focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
    }
    $(function(){
        $('#signUpForm').submit(function(e)){
            // Prevent the default submission regardless (as it will be handled via AJAX
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!Validation()){
                return false;
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : 'signup.php',
                    data : $(this).serialize()
                    beforeSend: function(){   
                        $("#error").fadeOut();
                    },
                    success: function(data){                        
                        if(data==2){
                            $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                                alert('Email is already taken.');
                                $("#email").focus();
                            });
                        } else if(data==1){
                            $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                                alert('Username is already taken.');
                                $("#username").focus();
                            });
                        } else if(data==3){
                                alert('Registration successfully submitted.');
                                window.location='index.php';
                        } else{
                                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');
                                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');
                                });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: should i still include `onsubmit="return Validation()"` in my form?

Comment: If you are using the jQuery approach, I don't believe that you would need it as the `e.preventDefault()` and `return false;` should take care of that if validation fails.

Comment: Could you post what your current code looks like? [This similar `Validation()` function](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/b9a5ca59b007976b87d3049eb32e45d3) should be similar to what you need.

Comment: Updated your code, you might want to give it a try now.

Comment: Do you still have the `onsubmit="return Validation();"` set on your form?

Comment: Have you tried placing a `debugger;` statement within your submit event and in your AJAX function to step through it as it executes? It might help indicate where there actual submission is taking place. (Just have your Developer Tools (F12) open and submit your form).